logrotate has deleted all my logfiles - what have I done wrong?
I thought I had set logrotate to keep the last 500 days of daily logfiles. However, 500 days later, they all appear to have been deleted, and it has started logging all over again.
Here is the config - what have I done wrong?
/etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate does not exist, so nothing is happening there.
There was a server restart around the same time which may have been a factor... however the server has been restarted previously with no such effect on the logging.
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 500
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate
        fi
    endscript
    postrotate
        if pgrep -f ^/usr/sbin/apache2 > /dev/null; then
            invoke-rc.d apache2 reload 2>&1 | logger -t apache2.logrotate
        fi
    endscript
}


how did you tested 500 day?!

Step 1. Create config file. Step 2. Wait 500 days.

So we will see us in one and a half year for the result?
